# Is there any formula for this given pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gamma-function

This problem troubling me, I have some clue to the distribution of these pattern it includes the gamma function(upcourse) and the triangular numbers, but i can't make any successful formulation: 
$$a_1=0!1$$
$$a_2=1!2$$
$$a_3=2!3+0!2$$
$$a_4=3!4+1!3$$
$$a_5=4!5+2!4$$
$$a_6=5!6+3!5+0!3$$
$$a_7=6!7+4!6+1!4$$
$$a_8=7!8+5!7+2!5$$
$$a_9=8!9+6!8+3!6$$
$$a_{10}=9!10+7!9+4!7+0!4$$
$$a_{11}=10!11+8!10+5!8+1!5$$
$$a_{12}=11!12+9!11+6!9+2!6$$
$$a_{13}=12!13+10!12+7!10+3!7$$
$$a_{14}=13!14+11!13+8!11+4!8$$
$$a_{15}=14!15+12!14+9!12+5!9+0!5$$ $${.....}$$ is there a formula for this?

Comment: I see every triangular number $n=\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$, $a_n$ adds an additional term $a_x$. Not sure how to write it though. Also what do you mean for "0!1"?

Comment: The first term, of the pattern..

Comment: There's the sum formula of $a_n = \sum_{0\leq t_k,t_{k+1}\leq n} (n-t_k)(n-t_{k+1})!$ where $t_k=0,1,3,6,10,\ldots$ ranges over the triangular numbers. Or did you mean a closed-formula?

Comment: So it's not like a particular value?

Comment: $a_n = \sum_{0\leq t_k,t_{k+1}\leq n} (n-t_k)(n-t_{k+1})!$ , Is there any closed form ranging the term of $a_{n}$ not to go negative $(-)$ e.i if $a_5=4!5+2!4+(-1)!2$? I already tried this formula but i think it doesn't fit..